# Deleted [favorite] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I just found the [favorite](/questions/tagged/favorite) tag (it has currently 21 questions). I think it needs to get removed, because...

- ...it doesn't make any sense to tag a question with it
- ...if it makes sense, it should belong on the meta site
- ...there is not a clear usage for it. Question tagged with it are related to the Twitter-, Facebook-, YouTube- and Android APIs or are talking about a custom favorite button and even about a SQL query (and the worst question is talking about 'favourite icons' instead of favicons...)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a Meta tag, it's used to describe questions about Favorite or Bookmark functionality in web browsers, and implementation dealing with that.  (Not saying all the questions currently tagged are using it correctly).

It should probably be synonymed to [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks).

Also, don't forget the 99 [favorites](/questions/tagged/favorites) questions.  We might have to start by synonyming to it instead.

Comment: are you sure it's talking about the Bookmark functionality? Only 2 of the 21 questions are about the Bookmark functionality.

Comment: if it's about bookmarking, I agree that it should be synonymed (and a lot of questions needs to get retagged)

Comment: @WouterJ, yeah, it's IMHO, but I think the tag is overused for too many things, just instead of burning it, we should synonym it.  Of course we need to remove it from the questions it doesn't belong on then.